# Why %@ behave differently between predicateWithFormat and stringWithFormat?

Tags: objective-c, predicate, stringwithformat

With predicateWithFormat, %@ becomes surrounded by "". We need to use %K for keys.

For example `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat @"%@ == %@" ,@"someKey",@"someValue"]` becomes

```
"someKey" == "someValue"
```

While at stringWithFormat, %@ is not surrounded by ""

```
[NSString stringWithFormat @"%@ == %@" ,@"someKey",@"someValue"]
```

becomes `someKey == someValue`

Why the difference?

Am I missing something?

Why use %@ for "Value" in predicateWithFormat because it's not what %@ mean in stringWithFormat. Why not create a new notation, say %V to get "Value" and %@ remain Value like in the stringWithFormat counterpart.

Why Apple decides that the same symbol, namely %@ should mean differently.

They really are different right? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

String variables are surrounded with quotation marks in predicates while dynamic properties (and hence keypaths) are not quoted. Consider this example:

Lets say we have an array of people:

```
NSArray *people = @[
    @{ @"name": @"George", @"age": @10 }, 
    @{ @"name": @"Tom", @"age": @15 }
    ];
```

Now if we wanted to filter our array in order to find all persons by name, we would expect a predicate that would expand to something like this:

```
name like[c] "George"
```

That way we say that `name` is a dynamic key and `George` is a constant string.
So, if we used a format like `@"%@ like[c] %@"` the expanded predicate would be:

```
"name" like[c] "George"
```

which is clearly not what we want (here both `name` and `George` are constant strings)

So the correct way to build our predicate would be:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like[c] %@", @"name", @"George"];
```

I hope that this makes sense. You can find much more on predicates in Apple's [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-CJBDBHCB)

Comment: I understand all about this before I ask the question. But why use %@ for "Value" in predicate. Why not create a new notation, say %V to get "Value" and %@ remain Value like in the stringWithFormat counterpart.

Comment: Well, that's not exactly right `%@` will add quotes only on string objects, if you use it with an `NSNumber` for example (`age == %@`) it will **not** quote the value (it will expand to `age == 10`).

Comment: I know but even for string objects %@ will not add quotes for stringWithFormat. So basically %@ behaves unusually for predicateWithFormat for string objects. Unusualness is bad.

Comment: No, it just behaves as it should be (at least imho). `stringWithFormat` is just a string after all. A predicate can be a composite expression which will be evaluated at some point. Finally the `%@` specifier is purposed as a substitution token for cocoa objects and that's exactly what it does in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Well, NSPredicate is a function to evaluate some string, [Look at this example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795)
and NSString stringWithFormat only copy the value that is given to the corresponding place -- %@.
The usage is totally different, and you can do a lot of complex operation with NSPredicate.